# Tweaking the "Press this" Wordpress bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, wordpress, bookmarklet

I'm using the default Wordpress "Press This" bookmarklet which is good, but I want to change a couple of things.

this is the code:

```
javascript:var%20d=document,w=window,e=w.getSelection,k=d.getSelection,x=d.selection,s=(e?e():(k)?k():(x?x.createRange().text:0)),f='http://superarsha.wordpress.com/wp-admin/press-this.php',l=d.location,e=encodeURIComponent,u=f+'?u='+e(l.href)+'&t='+e(d.title)+'&s='+e(s)+'&v=4';a=function(){if(!w.open(u,'t','toolbar=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,status=1,width=720,height=570'))l.href=u;};if%20(/Firefox/.test(navigator.userAgent))%20setTimeout(a,%200);%20else%20a();void(0)
```

what I want:
1: insert the URL in the first line.
2: replace the original title on the body with just "YouTube" link to the source page.

if number 2 is not clear then here's an example:
when "press this" on a youtube video, the body will come like this (video_title_here - YouTube).
what I want is just (YouTube)

Comment: actually I tried nothing, because I can't write codes !

Answer (score 3):

i posted this answer elsewhere as well:

You have to modify the `press-this.php` file in the wp-admin folder, as well as the bookmarklet javascript.

By default, wordpress will use the same information for both the post title and the link title, so you need to modify the press-this.php file so it separates the two.

Here is a pastebin link to a modified press-this.php: http://pastebin.com/5ZaYCpJ0

Here is the modified bookmarklet javascript:

```
javascript:var%20d=document,w=window,e=w.getSelection,k=d.getSelection,x=d.selection,s=(e?e():(k)?k():(x?x.createRange().text:0)),f='http://superarsha.wordpress.com/wp-admin/press-this.php',l=d.location,e=encodeURIComponent,r=/youtube.com/i,t=d.title,n=(r.test(l.href)?'YouTube':d.title),u=f+'?u='+e(l.href)+'&t='+e(t)+'&n='+e(n)+'&s='+e(s)+'&v=4';a=function(){if(!w.open(u,'t','toolbar=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,status=1,width=720,height=570'))l.href=u;};if%20(/Firefox/.test(navigator.userAgent))%20setTimeout(a,%200);%20else%20a();void(0)
```